# Web Project is failing to load in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I am getting below error when i try to open solution in Visual Studio.

"Creation of the virtual directory http://localhost://1111 failed with the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

However, same project loads fine, inside other solution file. Not sure what I am missing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Learn how to ask a proper question first please.

Comment: Hey, sorry for confusion, seems my screen shot not showing up in screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to default settings on the .vs folder. Look at "Properties > Advanced" window of the .vs folder in the solution directory and uncheck "Encrypt contents to secure data". That should resolve this issue without needing to re-install the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling visual studio resolved my issue.

Thanks